# Can MediaPlayer even stream MP3?

Tags: android, media-player

Either my webserver at codejanitor is not designed for streaming? or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I've tried the following two approaches:

```
try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                    AmazonClipActivity.this, 
                    Uri.parse("http://codejanitor.us/good.mp3"));
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();

                }
            });
        } finally {
            if(mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
                mp =null;
            }
        }
```

AND

```
try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                    AmazonClipActivity.this, 
                    Uri.parse("http://codejanitor.us/good.mp3"));
            mp.start();
        } finally {
            if(mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
                mp =null;
            }
        }
```

AND both produce:

```
05-19 12:27:48.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1730): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-19 12:27:48.104: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(68): setDataSource('http://codejanitor.us/good.mp3')
05-19 12:27:48.104: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(68): connect to codejanitor.us:80/good.mp3 @0
05-19 12:27:53.653: INFO/NuCachedSource2(68): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
```

Comment: Whaty version of Android are you running on?

Comment: compiled code for 2.2 , on 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965784/streaming-audio-from-a-url-in-android-using-mediaplayer) topic. None of the answers are marked, but there are a few solutions to how to get MediaPlayer to stream from a URL.