# audio stream not playing in Android webview Fragment

Tags: java, android, html, streaming, android-webview

I have an Android application with 4 tabs and I am trying to load a different webview into each tab. One of the webviews contains an audio stream. I am having 2 problems:

1. The Audio stream page will not load. The fragment loads to a blank white page for the audio stream webview.

   **ListenLiveFragment.java**

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment`

       View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen_live, container, false);
       web_v=(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
       WebSettings web_sett=web_v.getSettings();
       web_sett.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       web_v.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
       web_v.loadUrl("http://stream.us.gslb.liquidcompass.net/WPWXFMMP3");


       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen_live, container, false);
       //return v;
   }

   private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           web_v.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

**fragment_listen_live.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.peekatu.maintemplate.ListenLiveFragment">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />


</FrameLayout>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
      <source src="http://stream.us.gslb.liquidcompass.net/WPWXFMMP3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

2.My 2nd question is how do I stop the webviews from reloading every time the fragment is paused. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of using a webview, try to use MediaPlayer

You can quickly try with

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(URL_OF_FILE);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Or

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("SOURCE URL"));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

You have a better implementation here which loads the content in background without blocking the UI.

[Streaming Audio from A URL in Android using MediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965784/streaming-audio-from-a-url-in-android-using-mediaplayer/13740850#13740850)

2. About the second question, I assume that when you move around tabs, the Fragment is being created again and the webview is loaded again.

A first approach could be to tell the ViewPager to keep loaded these fragments increasing the size, in this case if you have four tabs

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Or save and restore the state of each fragment

Comment: Thank you for your help. One question. I am reviewing the link to the example you sent and in that example the stream is being loaded by the MainActivity with extends Activity. How do I load this example into a fragment. Do I just extend FragmentActivity? Thank you.